# Undefined symbol when loading php extension made with SWIG

Tags: php, c++, swig, libstdc++, shared-libraries

I am trying to load a PHP extension made using SWIG, but I am getting the following error when starting PHP:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/libtg.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/libtg.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0 in Unknown on line 0
```

The extension I am trying to load is named `libtg.so` and was compiled with the command:

```
g++ -shared libtg_wrap.o -o libtg.so
```

where `libtg_wrap.o` is the object file for the wrapper code generated by SWIG.

The missing symbol `__gxx_personality_v0` is found in `libstdc++.so`, as evident from the following command:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep __gxx_personality_v0
00000000000b9990 T __gxx_personality_v0
```

`libstdc++.so` is referenced in `libtg.so`, as evident from the following command:

```
$ ldd libtg.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5f932000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3fc937c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3fc90f9000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3fc8ee2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3fc8b5f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3fc98fc000)
```

so I don't see why it cannot find the symbol. Any ideas on how I can further debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that somewhere in your compile process, the compiler or linker was not aware of a c++ source.

When I tried swig (also to create a php extension), I created the following [Makefile](https://github.com/marcelog/SimplePcap/blob/master/GNUmakefile) that may be handy in your case, so you may want to customize it for your project and give it a try, it's pretty straighforward.

See how I had to specify the "-c++" option to the swig command. Also, be sure to have .cpp extension for your source files and add "-lstdc++" to your linker flags.

The important stuff should be the swig invocation (note the -c++ option):

```
${OUTPUTDIR}/${NAME}_swig.cpp:
    ${SWIG} -outdir ${OUTPUTDIR} \
        -oh ${OUTPUTDIR}/${NAME}_swig.h \
        -o ${OUTPUTDIR}/${NAME}_swig.cpp \
        -c++ -php \
        ${NAME}.i
```

and the linker invocation (note the -lstdc flag) :

```
ld -shared ${OUTPUTDIR}/*.o -o ${OUTPUTDIR}/${NAME}.so -lstdc++
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Interestingly, that worked! Previously I was using `g++` to link rather than `ld` directly... I wonder what's the difference.

Comment: Actually, there shouldn't be a difference, you can link by using g++. Since you are not showing how you compiled the .o file or how you invoked the swig command or any other details, I cant say much more.. but I'm glad it worked! :)

Comment: The .o file was compiled with `g++ \`php-config5 --includes\` -c -fPIC -std=c++0x libtg_wrap.cpp`, and the swig command was invoked as `swig -php -c++ libtg.i`.

Comment: I've tried linking with g++ like you did, and it works ok. Your g++ cli options look good too, but I couldn't test -std=c++0x in my box... I wonder if that's what made your build fail